# How to parse a string in json?

Tags: php, json

I have a string like this:

```
 0: array( 'name' => 'john', 'username' => 'foo' ) 1: array( 'name' => 'jack', 'username' => 'foo' )"
```

how I can encode it in json? I tried with:

```
$value = array_values($arr);
var_dump($value);
```

but I get `NULL`

UPDATE - If I do `json_encode($arr);` I get:

```
 ""\r\n 0: array(\r\n 'name' => 'john',\r\n 'username' => 'foo'\r\n )\r\n 1: array(\r\n 'name' => 'jack',\r\n 'username' => 'foo'\r\n )""
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard there is a problem with `json_encode` I get a bad encoding, check the update question.

Comment: How is your array built? It's encoding it like a string instead of an array.

Comment: @aynber how you can see in my first code, my array have space internally.

Comment: Let me rephrase: how did you create and build your array? Is it being passed from a form or database, or are you creating it within your code?

Comment: Maybe you have enabled the JSON_PRETTY_PRINT option?

Comment: @aynber I create the array which some database parameter I join the content with a schema like this `$schema = "   '%s' => '%s'";` and set the schema with `sprintf`.

Comment: Your "array" is really a string, and it won't encode as an array. I'd suggest building a correct array, then you can use it with json_encode.

Comment: I build the array with this: http://pastebin.com/AWW2UZMb

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) php function. I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Can you update with the line where you defined the array?

Comment: Uhm it's difficult for me, I have a lot of function for encode the array.. Anyway this is the function that return the array with space: http://pastebin.com/AWW2UZMb

Comment: The variable that your calling json_encode with is not an array. Looks like a string. Am I seeing this correctly?

Comment: Yes sorry for the error the function return a string not an array, let met correct the title.